# Understanding a proof regarding Borel-Cantelli lemma

Tags: real-analysis, probability

I came across this line of proof:

($\{Y_i\}_i$ are iid)

If $E|Y_i| < \infty$, then $\sum_n P( |Y_n| > \delta n) < \infty$ for all $\delta$.

Why is this so? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Got it. I had to use $E(|X|) = \int_0^\infty P( |X| > x) dx$.

Comment: Or so at least it seems.

Comment: Yes and you just break up the integral $\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} P(|X| > x)dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{\delta (n-1)}^{\delta n} P(|X| > x)dx > \delta \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(|X| > \delta n)$ The inequality follows from the fact that the integrand (the survival function of $|X|$ is a decreasing function)

Comment: @aduh Squarely offtopic here.

Comment: @Did Ok, thanks.

Comment: @Did Actually, would you mind saying what's wrong with my suggestion (now deleted--"squarely offtopic" is pretty discouraging) so that I can learn something from this? My idea was to prove the contrapositive of the statement in the OP. If the sum in the OP diverges, then by the BC-Lemma we have, with probability 1, that $|Y| > \delta n$ for infinitely many $n$. And from this it seems easy to show that $E|Y| = \infty$.

Comment: @aduh For which random variable $Y$? I see only random variables $Y_n$.

Comment: @Did Since they are identically distributed, can we just let $Y = Y_1$?

Comment: No we cannot, you seem to be confusing "having the same distribution" and "being almost surely equal".

Comment: @Did I think I see the mistake in my argument. Since the $Y_n$ are iid, $P(Y_n > \delta n) = P(Y_1 > \delta n)$, right? But making this substitution in the sum $\sum_n P(Y_1 > \delta n)$, we are no longer summing over probabilities of independent events, so the BC-lemma cannot be applied. Is this right?

Comment: @aduh More precisely, BC-lemma could be applied but it is irrelevant.

Comment: @Did How does BC apply to $\sum_n P(Y_1 > \delta n) = \infty$ if the events $\{ Y_1 > \delta n\}$ are not independent?

Comment: @aduh Hmmm, you seem to avoid reading what I write... Once again (last time): independence is offtopic here, BC-lemma is offtopic here, in some other situations it does happen that one must apply BC-lemma and then, but only then, to apply the part of BC-lemma that requires independence (which, anyway, is not the part when the series converges) then one should assume independence. Naturally.

Comment: @Did On the contrary, I'm reading you very closely and trying to learn. We agree that my suggestion was incorrect, but seem to disagree about _why_ it's incorrect. As I said above, my idea in invoking BC was to prove the _contrapositive_ of the OP statement, i.e. $\sum_n P(|Y_n| > \delta n) = \infty$ implies $E|Y_n| = \infty$. I agree, and it's obvious, that the BC lemma for convergent series is of no use here. Anyway, the idea is mistaken. Thank you for helping me understand that.